# How can I change the default loop wait time of 6 s in an imacro?

Tags: loops, timeout, imacros

My imacro script is below.  It is basically designed to save any pdf files found, however each iteration of the loop takes 6 sec.  Can this be changed to move on tot he next iteration without any wait time?

```
VERSION BUILD=10012816

TAB T=1

SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !LOOP 1000

URL GOTO=http://SOURCE/128268{{!LOOP}}-t.pdf

SAVEITEM 

TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should accomplish what you would like:

```
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0
```